# Expression: string subscript out of range console buffer

Tags: c++, buffer

I am trying to make an application that just prints some numbers into the console by putting it in a buffer first. I'm just testing it right now but (seemingly when the wchar_t values get copied over to the bufferArray) it's giving me this error message: Expression: string subscript out of range

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// initialising the buffer dimensions
int width = 8;
int height = 1;

int main()
{
    wchar_t bufferArray[8];
    int displayNum = 00000000;

    // creating access to the console buffer
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[width * height];
    HANDLE console = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(console);
    DWORD dBytesWritten = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // changing the displayNum int value to wchar[]
        wostringstream wss;
        wss << displayNum;
        wstring intValue = wss.str();

        // moving the values into the bufferArray wchar array (I just realized this step is unnecessary. I could just use the intValue array instead. It doesn't fix it though. I tried)
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            bufferArray[i] = intValue[i];
            if (intValue[i] == 0)
                bufferArray[i] = 0;
        }

        // putting the value into the screen buffer variable
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                screen[y * width + x] = bufferArray[x];
            }
        }

        // writing the buffer to the console
        screen[width * height - 1] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(console, screen, width * height, { 0,0 }, &dBytesWritten);

        // adding one to the number being displayed
        displayNum++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trust the debug facilities of your compiler.

Comment: `int displayNum = 00000000;` is the same as `int displayNum = 0;` padding with extra 0s has no effect.

Comment: Note that the leading 0 has no effect here, but it creates an octal literal. Octal 0 is the same as decimal 0, but `010` will be interpreted as 8, not 10.

Comment: In `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` the length of your string is 1 not 8:  see here: [https://ideone.com/9Jsymv](https://ideone.com/9Jsymv) so you go out of bounds when i == 1 on this line: `bufferArray[i] = intValue[i];`

Comment: Not 100% sure what your desired output is. That makes writing an answer that's actually useful to you, as opposed to simply making the crash go away, is hard. Crash is better for you than some hidden logic error. At least with the crash you know it's wrong.

Comment: I of course know that having 8 zeros there won't do anything. It's just that if I want to set a number at the beginning I can replace zeros instead of having to check if the number is 8 numbes long.

Comment: I just remembered that I asked this question. I'm gonna look over it after work and maybe update or validate an answer now that i have a better grasp.

Comment: I forgot this again. They were probably right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is correct, it looks like you're reading past the end of the string. You have `bufferArray[i] = intValue[i]` in a loop that runs 8 times regardless of how long the `intValue` string is.

It kind-of looks like you're trying to detect the end of `intValue` (by checking to see if `intValue[i]` is zero) and do something, but what you're doing isn't correct and doesn't exit the loop. Since `intValue` is a string, you should use `intValue.size()` to get the number of characters it contains, rather than looking for a null character at the end. Instead of running your loop 8 times, run it `min(8, intValue.size())` times.

After the above loop exits, you need to decide what goes into `bufferArray` after the end of the `intValue` string. Also, you may still need to null-terminate your `bufferArray`, since `bufferArray` is a raw array of characters. But if you're really using it as simply an array of characters and not a string, you may not need to null-terminate it.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the code. That's OK. I know what wnt wrong and how to fix it, but I'm still not sure exactly what the asker's trying to do, so any answer I give might not crash, but it could still do something very wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 I suppose you may be correct that I misinterpreted some of the code. However, I'm pretty confident that it's reading past the end of the `intValue` string, and that this should be avoided. :) I'm also not clear on what the asker is trying to do. Perhaps I should just delete this answer?  (There is now a comment pointing out the over-read of the buffer anyway.)

Comment: @user4581301 that can't be the problem because it doesn't even complete a single cycle of the while loop. I will add some comments so you can understand what I want to do (to sum it up I just want to display a number in the console with the number going up 1 every cycle of the while loop. It's just an excercise for learning how to write directly into the console buffer)

Comment: @nuuh you are most definitely going out of bounds on the string. In that Eric and I are 100% in agreement. We disagree a bit on what you're trying to do and how best to fix it. in `bufferArray[i] = intValue[i];` `intValue[i]` will go out of bounds when `i` is 2, so the code fails early in the `while` loop. Whatever you are trying to do, this won't do it. You could pad out `displayNum` with `setw` and `setfill` when you write it into the stream so that it's always 8 characters long and you can work backwards and divide `displayNum` by 10 and countless other options, but which fits best?

Comment: I wouldn't delete the answer, Eric. It diagnoses correctly and can help other people.